# Are setState updates in async event handlers batched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, dom-events, setstate

From what I understand in `react` versions 16 (current) and under, `setState` calls are batched IFF they are made in either component lifecycle events or event handlers. Otherwise, in order to batch calls there is an opt in `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` can be used.

If an event handler is an `async` function though, the browser will fire the event handler but then a promise will be returned, thus the actual event handler `Promise` callback won't be run until the next microtasks are picked up in the event loop. In other words, the `setState` updates do not actually occur in the immediate event handler.

Does this mean that we need to opt into `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` if we want `setState` updates to be batched in event handlers?

Answer (score 3):

After researching, I believe the answer is that the *initial* portion of the `async` event handler (that ends up translating to the executor function of the `Promise` that is returned underneath the hood) will have `setState` updates batched, but not anything after any `await` calls.

This is because everything in the `async` function body *before* the first `await` is translated to the executor function, which is executed within the browser event handler for the event, but everything after ends up as a chained `Promise` callback for the initial executor function, and these chained callbacks are executed on the microtask queue.

This is all because `async () => {}` is translated to something like `return new Promise().then()` where each then is a callback created for code after an `await` statement.

```
const onClick = async e => {
  // 1 and 2 will be batched
  setState(1)
  setState(2)

  await apiCall()

  // 3 and 4 will not be batched
  setState(3)
  setState(4)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below call will be batched by React and will cause single re-render.

```
const onClick = (e) => {
    setHeader('Some Header');
    setTitle('Some Tooltip');
};
```

Without `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates`, React would have made 2 `sync` calls to re-render components. Now it will have single re-render with this API.

```
const onClick = (e) => {
    axios.get('someurl').then(response => {
        ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
            setHeader('Some Header');
            setTitle('Some Tooltip');
        });
    });
};
```

Additional Notes:

1. We used it once in our project and it worked seamless. But I personally prefer to make a state as an object and update things at once rather than this approach. But I understand it is not always possible.
2. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-adoption.html) we can see that it is in Experimental mode, so not sure if you should use it in production.

**Update**

Based on the OP comment, below is the version for async await in JavaScript.

```
const onClick = async e => {

  setState(1);
  setState(2);
  await apiCall();

  ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
      setState(3);
      setState(4);
  });
}
```

The above code will trigger re-render 2 times. Once for update 1/2 and another for 3/4.

Comment: This does not address the `async` event handler portion.

Comment: @AdamThompson The answer was no for setters that execute after the event handler returned (async) unless you wrap it in `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates`.

Comment: Event handler to API is `async`. You can resolve a direct promise as well. I think that should cover up what you asked. Please provide little clarification if I misunderstood anything here.

Comment: See the answer I posted, the answer is that anything before the first `await` in an `async` event handler should be batched - please correct me if I am missing anything.